# Finding the closest values

Tags: r

I have a coding problem in R I am struggling with.

I have a dataset containing a time to a procedure and multiple times to images for different people. I would like to:

1. Subset the dataframe to only include those with a image preceding (within 24) and following the procedure (at any time)
2. Return a column giving the ID of the image closest before the procedure
3. return a column giving the ID of the image closest after the procedure

Reproducible example.

```
set.seed(123)

num_rows <- 100

unique_id <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(num_rows, 5)

time_to_procedure <- runif(num_rows, 0.5, 30)

data <- tibble(
  unique_id = unique_id,
  time_to_procedure = time_to_procedure
)

for (i in 1:6) {
  time_col_name <- paste0("time_to_image_", i)
  image_col_name <- paste0("image_id_", i)
  
  data[[time_col_name]] <- runif(num_rows, 0.5, 50)
  
  if (i > 1) {
    data[[time_col_name]] <- pmax(data[[time_col_name]], data[[paste0("time_to_image_", i - 1)]])
  }
  
  data[[image_col_name]] <- replicate(num_rows, paste0(sample(c(0:9, letters), 5, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
}

data <- data %>% arrange(time_to_image_1)

head(data)
```

Many thanks

Comment: You want the closest-before and closest-after for each row, so why are you adding six pairs of columns? It would help if your expected output (I'm assuming that's what `data` at the end is intended to represent) had actual matches, since (for instance) `data$image_id_1[1] %in% data$unique_id` is false.

Answer (score 3):

You say you want the closest before and the closest after, so here's a solution that identifies the (single) closest in either direction.

This method uses inequality-joins (self-join-self). Since we use `multiple="last"` and `="first"`, one requirement is that the `time_to_procedure` be in a known-order, so we'll first arrange by that.

```r
library(dplyr)
out <- data %>%
  left_join(data, join_by(closest(x$time_to_procedure > y$time_to_procedure)), suffix = c("", "_before")) %>%
  left_join(data, join_by(closest(x$time_to_procedure < y$time_to_procedure)), suffix = c("", "_after"))
# # A tibble: 100 × 6
#    unique_id time_to_procedure unique_id_before time_to_procedure_before unique_id_after time_to_procedure_after
#    <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>                               <dbl> <chr>                             <dbl>
#  1 oy66n                 0.977 NA                                 NA     uBH5D                              1.04
#  2 uBH5D                 1.04  oy66n                               0.977 eomyR                              1.25
#  3 eomyR                 1.25  uBH5D                               1.04  zF3gm                              1.44
#  4 zF3gm                 1.44  eomyR                               1.25  8YxaP                              1.60
#  5 8YxaP                 1.60  zF3gm                               1.44  dBrkf                              1.67
#  6 dBrkf                 1.67  8YxaP                               1.60  m0mjd                              1.91
#  7 m0mjd                 1.91  dBrkf                               1.67  tok97                              2.29
#  8 tok97                 2.29  m0mjd                               1.91  8eLeJ                              2.35
#  9 8eLeJ                 2.35  tok97                               2.29  tF2Kx                              2.86
# 10 tF2Kx                 2.86  8eLeJ                               2.35  cQX3G                              2.90
# # ℹ 90 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

(A previous version of this answer pre-sorted the data and used `multiple="first"` and such; the use of `closest(..)` removes the need to do that.)

With this, one can easily add a filter for those that don't match your "within 24" (hours?), perhaps with:

```r
out %>%
  mutate(
    across(ends_with("_before"),
           ~ if_else(time_to_procedure - time_to_procedure_before > 24, .[NA], .)
    )
  )
```

This code will replace *both* `unique_id_before` and `time_to_procedure_before` with `NA` if it is more than 24 prior to the row's procedure.

The reason I use `.[NA]` as a replacement is mostly declarative than safe: R has at least six kinds of `NA`, and some tools don't like blending `NA` (logical) with `NA_real_` or `NA_character_` without explicit casts. I'm just being safe, feel free to use `NA` if you trust everything will be fine (keeping it here costs you nothing).

---

Data

```r
data <- structure(list(unique_id = c("oy66n", "uBH5D", "eomyR", "zF3gm", "8YxaP", "dBrkf", "m0mjd", "tok97", "8eLeJ", "tF2Kx", "cQX3G", "C7ktN", "5oQkf", "sMHAA", "GEgHo", "cIO9r", "DNbL6", "hXaH9", "npELr", "mAPTr", "SPe9Z", "hLPou", "xYKzE", "xSgZ6", "bKUxT", "EE4Fj", "vI3wi", "FDaGW", "77gQp", "8ESGr", "qJhGa", "HmPsw", "tubP9", "tgdze", "2WtYS", "BwJT1", "iOyxj", "cHjpJ", "RoonR", "alNlX", "mB1PT", "VLeNM", "FfPm6", "2Rn7Y", "EG67z", "TlDJE", "DoJgv", "I64sk", "eJJDM", "WLE3E", "s04Al", "O4E3f", "GJzcw",  "xtgn1", "P7WDU", "8xVAc", "yIjm6", "vsfwW", "hl9Mf", "jyS4e", "8BtJM", "qI9h6", "2z2Ku", "l8OD3", "b6U69", "z958g", "OZDRD", "xmCJy", "kdi0T", "cNWsa", "Hxjg3", "OSi3L", "QztsA", "ExbVO", "XfAdJ", "Uhddy", "Rh5Lg", "Bm5SV", "XjDPG", "TGZut", "TFDf2", "JpDUH", "OCp9n", "f5NHo", "XdaJt", "z8uZO", "Rc0Dh", "MyOEc", "ZKL1V", "y4Sh5", "ctfjW", "zfPKp", "T90SU", "qUOF6", "8PPM9", "QLrSX", "OTYhu", "yRSAa", "HajAr", "JP0Bq"), time_to_procedure = c(0.976734186871909, 1.04174046975095, 1.25303760415409,  1.44316302833613, 1.60241396387573, 1.66522633668501, 1.90744455566164, 2.29307563370094, 2.34817495127209, 2.85920091357548, 2.90326352056582, 2.93466985807754, 3.10671737976372, 3.20351849647705, 4.04699529299978, 4.96447605767753, 5.56643047649413, 5.75140753109008, 6.43187817488797, 6.54569173802156, 8.59908822667785, 8.66722463793121, 8.81344425620046, 8.96945385541767, 9.3837044716347, 9.43518492556177, 9.70732736191712, 10.1641232707771, 10.4561024205759, 10.5689778765664, 10.7872250647051,  10.9313792414032, 11.2577953255968, 11.2809009524062, 11.310022626305, 11.3529304591939, 11.8626213354291, 12.1599859624403, 12.171988879214, 12.6925095386105, 12.9921777038835, 13.6875913481927, 13.9154681239743, 14.2090563375968, 14.9568718662485, 15.3664870046778, 15.4969335774658, 15.540365532157, 15.8047452402534, 16.0344073462766, 16.1265656977193, 16.1318275281228, 16.29847105511, 16.3135847585509, 16.6371908209985, 16.8227626330918, 17.2186554415384, 17.2967885482358, 17.6908222312341, 17.8152803751873,  17.8301103269914, 19.6827142613474, 19.7861171299592, 20.1391867048806, 20.1678021562984, 20.5308957633097, 20.7844236609526, 21.4166181521723, 22.2090308360057, 22.301434722729, 22.716747937724, 23.1939233916346, 23.221040403354, 24.1279722517356, 24.1660274041351, 24.4629924421897, 24.4791542930761, 24.5449041052489, 24.5861050942913, 24.96289929247, 25.0471793393372, 25.695949337096, 25.7037600212498, 25.8731519595021, 26.2815224288497, 26.420883626095, 26.4825413896469, 26.6114132205257, 26.6976281180978,  26.8828714508563, 27.1453900279012, 27.2284192927182, 27.9158451347612, 28.2045828177361, 28.3785355525324, 28.51276702818, 28.9425008184044, 29.0866464781575, 29.3328155155759, 29.6778089867439)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we need to subset the dataframe to include only those cases where there's an image preceding (within 24 hours) and following the procedure.
Find the ID of the image closest before the procedure and find the ID of the image closest after the procedure.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

set.seed(123)
num_rows <- 100
unique_id <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(num_rows, 5)
time_to_procedure <- runif(num_rows, 0.5, 30)

data <- tibble(
  unique_id = unique_id,
  time_to_procedure = time_to_procedure
)

for (i in 1:6) {
  time_col_name <- paste0("time_to_image_", i)
  image_col_name <- paste0("image_id_", i)

  data[[time_col_name]] <- runif(num_rows, 0.5, 50)

  if (i > 1) {
    data[[time_col_name]] <- pmax(data[[time_col_name]], 
data[[paste0("time_to_image_", i - 1)]])
  }

  data[[image_col_name]] <- replicate(num_rows, paste0(sample(c(0:9, 
letters), 5, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
}

# Transform the data from wide to long format
long_data <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("time_to_image_"),
               names_to = "time_col",
               values_to = "time_to_image") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("image_id_"),
               names_to = "image_col",
               values_to = "image_id") %>%
  filter(str_replace(time_col, "time_to_image_", "") == 
str_replace(image_col, "image_id_", ""))

# Function to find the closest image
find_closest_image <- function(time_to_procedure, times, ids) {
  diff_times <- times - time_to_procedure
  closest_before <- max(diff_times[diff_times < 0])
  closest_after <- min(diff_times[diff_times > 0])

  closest_before_id <- ids[which(diff_times == closest_before)]
  closest_after_id <- ids[which(diff_times == closest_after)]

  return(c(before = closest_before_id, after = closest_after_id))
}

# Applying the function to each unique_id
result <- long_data %>%
  group_by(unique_id) %>%
  summarise(
    closest_before = find_closest_image(time_to_procedure[1], time_to_image, image_id)["before"],
    closest_after = find_closest_image(time_to_procedure[1], time_to_image, image_id)["after"]
   )

# Merging the result with the original data
 final_data <- data %>%
 left_join(result, by = "unique_id")

head(final_data)
```